# How to monitor a port using Nagios Core?

Tags: linux, nagios

I want to know how for example If I want to monitor an IP with a port number ?

For example 192.168.100.100:8000 how could I monitor this using Nagios Core ?

I really need your help and thanks in advance

Best Regards

Comment: This website is focused on programming and your question is out of scope. Besides that, this is very common stuff and there are plenty of articles on the internet.

Answer (score -1):

You can use `netcat`. This is the command to check you case:

```
nc -zv 192.168.100.100 8000
```

Then you wrap this in sample shell script and create probe in Nagios.